# Group data by property and time interval

Tags: javascript, c#, typescript

I have a class looking like this:

```
public class UserAction
{
        public int LogId { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public CrudAction Action { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date{ get; set; }
}
```

The purpose of this class is to store information on who performed changes on a form in my web app. On the form you can open up a modal which displays these changes and when it happened.

Now, the issue is that the form has auto save which saves the form after each change made, which can generate plenty of log posts within short time intervals and therefore look a bit messy. When I open the modal to look at the logs it often looks something like this:

```
User        User action  Date and time of action
Lisa        Edited       2018-05-20 09:46 AM GMT+2
Tom         Edited       2018-05-18 11:18 AM GMT+2
Tom         Edited       2018-05-18 11:18 AM GMT+2
Tom         Edited       2018-05-18 11:18 AM GMT+2
Tom         Edited       2018-05-18 11:16 AM GMT+2
Tom         Edited       2018-05-18 11:15 AM GMT+2
Tom         Edited       2018-05-18 11:15 AM GMT+2
Tom         Edited       2018-05-18 11:15 AM GMT+2
Tom         Edited       2018-05-18 10:12 AM GMT+2 
Lisa        Edited       2018-05-16 13.28 PM GMT+2
Lisa        Posted       2018-05-16 13.25 PM GMT+2
```

I'm looking for a clever way to somehow group all the posts generated within the same hour by the same person with the same action and only show the latest post. Something like this:

```
User        User action  Date and time of action
Lisa        Edited       2018-05-20 09:46 AM GMT+2
Tom         Edited       2018-05-18 11:18 AM GMT+2
Tom         Edited       2018-05-18 10:12 AM GMT+2 
Lisa        Edited       2018-05-16 13.28 PM GMT+2
Lisa        Posted       2018-05-16 13.25 PM GMT+2
```

My app is an angular 5 app and I'm using a .Net Core Web API to get the data from an SQL database. I guess the logic for this could be in both the angular app or web api but maybe it is more preferable to do this on the client?

I have tried to make this work both in javascript and LINQ but I'm not getting very far (something is not clicking in my brain) so any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you never want to show the data that is filtered away by your grouping, it would be better to filter the data already on the server side. The reason is that otherwise you will transport unnecessary data to the client just do remove them anyways. This would slow your app down. Only transport the data that you need.

In the Web API controller, you can use the power of LINQ. The trick is to introduce a custom `IEqualityComparer<UserAction>` that implements your requirements, then feed it to the `Distinct` method.

```
UserAction[] userActions = dbContext.UserActions.ToArray();
var distinctActions = userActions
    .OrderByDescending(ua => ua.Date)             // sort as you like here
    .Distinct(new UserNameActionAndHourComparer());   // apply filter

public class UserNameActionAndHourComparer : IEqualityComparer<UserAction> {

    public bool Equals(UserAction left, UserAction right){
        if (left == null && right == null) {
             return true;
        }
        if (left == null | right == null) {
            return false;
        }

        // your equality criteria here ...
        if (left.UserName == right.UserName && left.Action == right.Action) {
            // implement requirement that same hour is considered equal
            return left.Date.Date == right.Date.Date && left.Date.Hour == right.Date.Hour;
        }
        return false;
   }

    // if two UserActions are considered equal, they should yield the same hashcode
    public int GetHashCode(UserAction ua) {
        return ua.UserName.GetHashCode() 
            ^ ua.Action.GetHashCode() 
            ^ new DateTime(ua.Date.Year, ua.Date.Month, ua.Date.Day, ua.Date.Hour, 0, 0).GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

[C# Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/M9gMtA)